# Fancybox 2 - Button Helper gallery "length" too large

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Fancybox 2  wrong "this.group.length" value

My galleries display N+1 or N+2 images (3 of 3 for two images, 12 of 12 for ten images) with last image repeated. The variable "length" is too large. Happens on web (Opera) and internally when I "test in browser" (Firefox)

See at http://www.pinacate.org/index.html click on thumb at "monogenetic volcanoes (2)" and at "gallery of images (10)"

EXAMPLE CODE:
    
    
        Description paragraph

image links on page appended after  tag

```
<div style="display:none"><!-- gallery of photos -->
    <a class="fancybox-buttons" 
    href="image.jpg" 
    data-fancybox-group="mono" 
    title="title."> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming fancybox 2.1.0 modify jquery.fancybox.js line that reads

```
D.undelegate(selector, 'click.fb-start').delegate(selector + ":not('.fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav')", 'click.fb-start', run);
```

to include your custom classes for exclusion or add one of the already excluded classes to the extra links you want to ignore.

Comment: Version old, downloaded 2.1.0 and problem went away.

Comment: Wrote too soon. I did download 2.1.0 and install it and the gallery count was correct last night. This morning after a W-7 re-boot, galleries are again 2 over.  I am a geologist, not a coder, and i do not understand how to implement your suggestion. Would you be so kind as to explain it to me.

Comment: The simplest way is to add `class="fancybox-item"` or `class="fancybox-nav"` to the elements where the duplicate pictures come from. If that changes their appearance, add `.someWeirdClassName` to the line mentioned in my above post between the apostrophes inside the `:not()` clause and `class="someWeirdClassName"` to your elements. If what I just said doesn't make any sense to you ask someone to fix it for you as I can't imagine stating it any more clearly than this.

Comment: xception, thanks for the help but if you "can't imagine stating it any more clearly," you need to get out more and talk to people who don't code Javascript. I'll take you to see the world's goddamndest volcano where the elements are calcium and silicon in the ion soup called magma.

Comment: I tried your suggestions in the "item" class which I assume is the element you referred to. no joy. Is this a bug I can't fix? I found no :not() clause in my copy of jquery.fancybox.js v2.1.0 on that line.

Comment: funny cause I copied the code I put in my answer from jquery.fancybox.js version 2.1.0 and there is a :not in it

Comment: xception: I had the wrong versions. I went back to zero, searched fancybox 2, and got a download from fancyapps that was different from what I got four days ago thinking it was 2.1.0. What I had was version: 2.0.3 (29/11/2011), what I got today was version: 2.1.0 (Mon, 20 Aug 2012) and it had the :not() clause. I moved all of the files I intend to use on pinacate.org to one "fancy2" folder and adjusted the references in my index.html page. When I ran it in Firefox, it worked except for "this.group.length" being 1 or 2 too large - the original problem.

Comment: I added ".shortem" (my class for displaying thumbnail and text on the html page) to the :not() clause, I put a reference to class="fancybox-item" in the  "Gallery of Pinacate images" shortem div on the html page, I did the "SomeWeirdClassName" thing - no joy. This is well beyond my pay-grade. It is, however, an annoyance that will not affect my story-telling on pinacate.org. The world's goddamndest volcano vexes me and it may-well kill me if I'm not careful but I'm more comfortable not understanding the rock. Thanks for your help.

Comment: xception: I thank you for your help but I think this is an issue for Janis Skarnelis, I found her e-mail in the js file. This might be as interesting a problem for a coder as my geologist's problem of explaining how multi-ton rocks flew. Here endeth this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is an innocent omission (understandable when you are not a coder ;)

You need to close properly your anchors (the `<a>` tags) so fancybox can count properly how many elements per gallery ...so this piece of code

```
<div style="display:none"><!-- gallery of photos -->
    <a class="fancybox-buttons" 
    href="image.jpg" 
    data-fancybox-group="mono" 
    title="title."> 

</div>
```

should be :

```
<div style="display:none"><!-- gallery of photos -->
    <a class="fancybox-buttons" 
    href="image.jpg" 
    data-fancybox-group="mono" 
    title="title."></a>

</div>
```

**NOTICE** that I added the closing tag `</a>` at the end of the anchor to close it properly. Do the same for each of them.

Comment: Duuhhh! See what I mean about knowing just enough code to be dangerous? Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem.